# How to Detect Only Hand Movement using OpenCV HSV and Background Subtraction?

Tags: python, opencv, gesture-recognition

I am having difficulty creating a detector for hand and its movement due to the program didn't run when I put BgSubtraction and HSV codes altogether. It can only run with HSV code with the following result

[image: The camera detects hand and the background]

The code is in python and I got it from OpenCV doc with a few modifications
here's the [link](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d97/tutorial_threshold_inRange.html)

What I want is for the camera to detect only the hand model without noise and the background, I read it in a journal and it needs HSV Thresholding and Background Subtraction. Is it possible? Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://github.com/BlueDi/Hand-Detection)?

Comment: @Ahmet I did not, I'll check it out, thanks for the information

Comment: Where is the source image